# how to retrieve aws batch parameter value in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-batch

Flow :- Dynamo DB --> Lambda --> Batch

If a role arn is inserted in *dynamo DB*, it is retrieved from lambda event, it is then submitted to batch using `submit_job` API with role arn being passed as

```
parameters={
    'role_arn': 'arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/role_name'
}
```

How to read the parameter value in python running in batch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to specify the parameter reference in your docker file or in AWS Batch job definition command like this

```
/usr/bin/python/pythoninbatch.py Ref::role_arn
```

In your Python file **pythoninbatch.py** handle the argument variable using **sys package or argparse libray**.

```
sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I tried adding the argument in job definition and used sys package to retrieve the role_arn.

Comment: Finally, someone makes this very clear. This was not at all obvious to me from the AWS Batch documentation. Thank you!