# I am not able to pass parameter in aws batch job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dockerfile, parameter-passing, aws-batch

I have a `Dockerfile` with the following lines:

```
FROM python
COPY sysargs.py /
CMD python sysargs.py --date Ref::date
```

And my python file `sysargs.py` looks like this:

```
import sys
print('The command line arguments are:')
a = sys.argv[1]
print(a)
```

I just want to pass parameter date and print the date but after passing date value I am getting output as "Ref::date".

Can someone help me what I have done wrong?

I am trying to replicate as mentioned in [how to retrieve aws batch parameter value in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718444/how-to-retrieve-aws-batch-parameter-value-in-python).

Comment: **From where** do you want to pass the argument and what is `Ref::date` supposed to do?

Comment: we will pass this argument while submitting job in aws batch job

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718444/how-to-retrieve-aws-batch-parameter-value-in-python#new-answer this is similar to what i have tried

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your Dockerfile `Ref::date` is just a string, hence that is what is printed as output in the python script.

If you want date to be a value passed in from an external source, then you can use `ARG`. Take 10 minutes to read through [this guide](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/).

Comment: @ Matthew Hegarty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718444/how-to-retrieve-aws-batch-parameter-value-in-python#new-answer

Comment: please hsve look at above link i was trying to replicate same thing.

Comment: am in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223808/aws-batch) - will help if i can

Answer (score -1):

## My experience with AWS Batch "parameters"

I have been working on a project for about 4 months now. One of my tasks was to connect several AWS services together to process in the Cloud the last uploaded file that an application had placed in a S3 bucket.

### What I needed

The way this works is the following. Through a website, a user uploads a file that is sent to a back-end server, and then to a S3 bucket. This event triggers a AWS Lambda function, which inside creates and runs an instance of a AWS Batch Job, that has already been defined previously (based on a Docker image) and would retrieve from the S3 bucket the file to process it and the save in a database some results. By the way, all the code I am using is done with Python.

Everything worked as charm until I found it really hard to get as a *parameter* the filename of the file in the S3 bucket that generated the event, inside the python script that was being executed inside the Docker container, run by the AWS Batch Job.

### What I did

After a lot of research and development, I came up with a solution for my problem. The issue was based on the fact that the word "parameter", for AWS Batch Jobs, is not what a user may expect. In return, we need to use *containerOverrides*, the way I show below: defining an "environment" variable value inside the running container by providing a pair of *name* and *value* of that variable.

```html
# At some point we had defined aws_batch like this:
#
#aws_batch = boto3.client(
#    service_name="batch",
#    region_name='<OurRegion>',
#    aws_access_key_id='<AWS_ID>',
#    aws_secret_access_key='<AWS_KEY>',
#)

aws_batch.submit_job(
    jobName='TheJobNameYouWant',
    jobQueue='NameOfThePreviouslyDefinedQueue',
    jobDefinition='NameOfThePreviouslyDefinedJobDefinition',
    # parameters={              #THIS DOES NOT WORK
    #     'FILENAME': FILENAME  #THIS DOES NOT WORK
    # },                        #THIS DOES NOT WORK
    containerOverrides={
        'environment': [
            {
                'name': 'filename',
                'value': 'name_of_the_file.png'
            },
        ],
    },
)
```

This way, from my Python script, inside the Docker container, I could access the environment variable value using the well-known `os.getenv('<ENV_VAR_NAME>')` function.

You can also check on your AWS console, under the Batch menu, both Job configuration and Container details tabs, to make sure everything makes sense. The container that the Job is running will never *see* the Job parameters. In the opposite way, it will know the environment variables.

[image: Job configuration tab]

[image: Container details]

### Final notes

I do not know if there is a better way to solve this. So far, I share with all the community something that does work.
I have tested it myself, and the main idea came from reading the links that I list below:

- [AWSBatchJobs parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/example-job-definitions.html?icmpid=docs_console_unmapped#example-use-parameters) (Use just as context info)
- [submit_job function AWS Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.16.0/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.submit_job) (Ideal to learn about what kind of actions we are allowed to do or configure when creating a job)

I honestly hope this helps you and wish you a happy coding!